# Verify that the sets B and S are spanning sets for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:** Express the vector $v=(1,2,3)$ in term of the standard basis $\{ e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then verify that the sets $B=\{(1,1,0),(1,2,0),(2,1,1) \}$ and $S=\{(1,1,0),(1,2,0),(2,1,1),(0,1,1) \}$ are spanning sets for $\mathbb{R}^3$, and express v in terms of B and S.

$\textbf{Express the vector v in term of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.}$

$$ v=(1,2,3) = (1,0,0)e_1+(0,2,0)e_2+(0,0,3)e_3 $$

Is this correct?

$\textbf{Verify that the sets B and S are spanning sets for $\mathbb{R}^3$.}$

$det(B)= \begin{Vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 1\\
\end{Vmatrix}$
= $1\cdot \begin{Vmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \end{Vmatrix}-1\cdot \begin{Vmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \\ \end{Vmatrix}+0\cdot \begin{Vmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \\ \end{Vmatrix}=2-1=1\neq 0$

Hence B is a spanning set for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$det(S)= \begin{Vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{Vmatrix}$

How do I compute the determinant for S?

$\textbf{Express v in terms of B and S.}$

I have no idea where to start for here.

Comment: You have to show Rank($S$) = 3, and find a subset of S with 3 elements that spans $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Thank you both for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer is incorrect, as math_man already pointed out.

For checking whether the sets are spanning, you can use row reduction.

Consider the matrix where the given vectors form the *columns* and row reduce it:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2\\
1&2&1\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2\\
0&1&-1\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(second row minus first row). This is a row-echelon form, with a pivot in each column, so the rank of the matrix is $3$ and the set $B$ is a spanning set.

For the set $S$ it's the same:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2&0\\
1&2&1&2\\
0&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2&0\\
0&1&-1&2\\
0&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is again in row echelon form.

Note, however, that once you know $B$ is a spanning set, also $S$ is such, because it includes $B$.

Just to do a different example, suppose the second vector in each set is $(1,0,1)$, so the second matrix becomes
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2&0\\
1&0&1&2\\
0&1&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now the row reduction is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2&0\\
1&0&1&2\\
0&1&1&1
\end{bmatrix}\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2&0\\
0&-1&-1&2\\
0&1&1&1
\end{bmatrix}\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2&0\\
0&-1&-1&2\\
0&0&0&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(first transformation: subtract first row from second row; second transformation: sum second row to third row) and in this case the pivots are in the first, second and fourth column. Thus the set corresponding to the first three columns is *not* a spanning set, while the four vector set *is* a spanning set.

Expressing $v$ in terms of $B$ is solving a linear system:
$$v=\alpha_1 v_1+\alpha_2 v_2+\alpha_3 v_3$$
which again can be done with row reduction: add a column corresponding to $v$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2&1\\
1&2&1&2\\
0&0&1&3
\end{bmatrix}\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2&1\\
0&1&-1&1\\
0&0&1&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now go backwards; sum the third row to the second row and $-2$ times the third row to the first row:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&-5\\
0&1&0&4\\
0&0&1&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the last step is subtracting the second row from the first row:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&-9\\
0&1&0&4\\
0&0&1&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This tells you that $\alpha_1=-9$, $\alpha_2=4$ and $\alpha_3=4$.

Also expressing $v$ in terms of $S$ is possible, but will have infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Your first answer is NOT corect, you have expressed incorrectly the vector,the correct expression is $(1,2,3)=1e_1+2e_2+3e_3= 1\cdot(1,0,0)+2\cdot(0,1,0)+3\cdot(0,0,1)$ canonic base o f $\mathbb{R}^3$
, the matrix
$det(S)= \begin{Vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{Vmatrix}$
is not square, then you can not calculate the determinant of this matrix
The set of vector gave is not linear idependent, since you have a 4 vector in a space of dimension 3. So you have to take three by three and verify if the det of the matriz 3x3 is non zero for one of this combinations. If this set span $\mathbb{R}^3$ then you choose the triple that the det of the matriz is non zero and write in the basis as the following process:

If you have a basis, $v_1, v_2, v_3 $and a vector $ w $  to write  in this base, then you have to sove a linear equation, that is
$w =a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3$
you will generate a linear sistem of 3 variables and 3 equations. solve the sistem and than you write the vector on the base, remember, you will find values to $a_i$ $i=1,2,3$.